# Laracel api resource Conditional Attributes not working, when processing Auth::check()

Tags: laravel-9, jsonapi-resources

```
'likedPosts' => $this->when(Auth::check(), function () {
                    return $this->likedPosts;
                }),
```

When the current user is `logged in` or when `Auth::check()` returns `true`, the resource response should appear.

But it's not working, I am not sure why. look at the following pictures

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be doing it in `web.php`, cause `api.php` do nothing with `auth`.

```
Route::prefix('api')->middleware('auth')->group(function() {
    Route::apiResource('/explore/gallery', App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class);
});
```